# Get page element text without html tags but keep linebreaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get text from elements on a page.  I don't want the html tags but I want the linebreaks.  If I do a `$('#element').text()` the linebreaks are removed.  What is the way to keep the paragraphs from the element without the html tags?

Comment: So do you want the text that is displaying on the user's screen to keep the linebreaks? Because that would be a little different than the carriage returns (I believe).

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the line brk.

Comment: So you want to remove all html _except_ for the `<br />` tags?

Comment: You don't want the HTML, but you do want the linebreaks, `text()` preserves linebreaks ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5fQGS/)), that is it preserves `\n` etc. Do you really mean you would like to keep some of the HTML, like `<p>` and `<br>` but not the rest etc. and if so what exactly is it you don't want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to extract the HTML, replace all `<p>`, `</p>` and `<br>` tags with certain strings, then transform the HTML into text using jQuery's `.text`, then replace those certain strings with `\n`s.

This is far from a perfect solution, but it might be enough for your case.